# Rails Simple Form error: No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app with Simple Form and Bootstrap.

I have a form, which has two fields in it, as follows:

```
 <%= f.input :type, 'What sort of equipment or materials are you seeking?' %>
  <%= f.input :description, 'What are your project requirements for the equipment or materials?' %>
```

When I try to have a look at the form - I get an error which says: 'no implicit conversion of symbol to integer).

I don't have any arrays that seem to be the subject of other people's problems.  Does anyone see what the problem is?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is a hash, not a string.  If you wanted your string to be a label:

```
<%= f.input :type, { label: 'What of equipment or materials are you seeking' } %>
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder#input-instance_method